# Parse - No placeholder and field email doesn't work in SignUpViewController

Tags: parse-platform

I have a problem in Parse with my signUpView.

When I try with LogInAndSignUpDemo code (the Parse tutorial) it works well.

For my project, I have a button "log in" in my view, when the user selects "log in", I open the LogInviewController. If the user doesn't have an account, he can "sign up".
When he sign up, he has this view :  [Image of mysignupview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ovZB.png)
My problem is on this view because I don't have placeholder for password and email fields, and I can't select the email field.

My code :

```
-(IBAction) bouton_log_in_action:(id)sender
{
    if (![PFUser currentUser]) { // No user logged in
        // Create the log in view controller
        PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
        [logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

        // Create the sign up view controller
        PFSignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[PFSignUpViewController alloc] init];
        [signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

        // Assign our sign up controller to be displayed from the login controller
        [logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController]; 

        // Present the log in view controller
        [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

I don't understand where is the problem, because I use the code I found on Parse documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
It's a bug, it'll be fix in 1.2.21 release...

Comment: Any ETA for 1.2.21? Or any way to work around the problem with 1.2.20?

Comment: @Richard Casey For the ETA, on the bugtracker, they said on July 30 that the 1.2.21 will be release in two weeks. I work around the problem using the 1.2.19, you cand find it here : https://parse.com/downloads/ios/parse-library/1.2.19

Comment: Thanks @saraza. Switched back to 1.2.19 and the Signup screen works again!